# failed to launch Openstack instance when integrating with ODL

Tags: openstack

I tried to integrate Openstack train with Opendaylight magnesium and my references were [[1]](https://docs.opendaylight.org/projects/netvirt/en/stable-magnesium/openstack-guide/openstack-with-netvirt.html) and [[2]](https://files.openstack.org/docs/networking-odl/train/install/installation.html) but after doing all the steps, the instance failed to launch. I changed port_binding_controller in [ml2_odl] section in the ml2_conf.ini file from pseudo-agentdb-binding to legacy-port-binding and then the instance launched but the status of router interfaces was still down.

I have a controller node and a compute node. and Opendaylight runs on the controller node.

**nova-compute.log:**

```
INFO nova.virt.libvirt.driver [-] [instance: 975fa79e-6567-4385-be87-9d12a8eb3e94] Instance destroyed successfully.
2021-01-02 12:33:23.383 25919 ERROR vif_plug_ovs.ovsdb.impl_vsctl [req-a0a7ebf0-7e63-4c60-a8d2-07c05f1aa4f4 04c7685a2166481a9ace54eb5e71f6e5 ca28ee1038254649ad133d5f09f7a186 - default default] Unable to execute ['ovs-vsctl', '--timeout=120', '--oneline', '--format=json', '--db=tcp:127.0.0.1:6640', '--', '--if-exists', 'del-port', 'br-int', 'tap50eb0b68-a4']. Exception: Unexpected error while running command.
Command: ovs-vsctl --timeout=120 --oneline --format=json --db=tcp:127.0.0.1:6640 -- --if-exists del-port br-int tap50eb0b68-a4
Exit code: 1
Stdout: ''
Stderr: 'ovs-vsctl: tcp:127.0.0.1:6640: database connection failed (Connection refused)\n': oslo_concurrency.processutils.ProcessExecutionError: Unexpected error while running command.
```

**controller ovs:**

```
Manager "tcp:192.168.222.48:6640"
        is_connected: true
    Bridge br-int
        Controller "tcp:192.168.222.48:6653"
            is_connected: true
        fail_mode: secure
        Port tune52c5c73a50
            Interface tune52c5c73a50
                type: vxlan
                options: {key=flow, local_ip="10.0.0.31", remote_ip="10.0.0.11"}
        Port br-int
            Interface br-int
                type: internal
    Bridge br-ex
        Port br-ex
            Interface br-ex
                type: internal
        Port ens160
            Interface ens160
    ovs_version: "2.13.1"
```

**compute ovs:**

```
Manager "tcp:192.168.222.48:6640"
        is_connected: true
    Bridge br-int
        Controller "tcp:192.168.222.48:6653"
            is_connected: true
        fail_mode: secure
        Port br-int
            Interface br-int
                type: internal
        Port tun34b3712d975
            Interface tun34b3712d975
                type: vxlan
                options: {key=flow, local_ip="10.0.0.11", remote_ip="10.0.0.11"}
        Port tund5123ce5b8a
            Interface tund5123ce5b8a
                type: vxlan
                options: {key=flow, local_ip="10.0.0.11", remote_ip="10.0.0.31"}
    ovs_version: "2.13.1"
```